# Foreign key violation when adding child class to session in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the current situation:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(String(32), primary_key=True, index=True)


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    parent_id = Column(ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
    other_field = Column(String(32))


class Other(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'other'

    id = Column(String(32), primary_key=True, index=True)
    reference_to_parent = Column(ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)


child = Child(id='some_id', other_field="blah")
session.add(child)

other = Other(id="some_other_id", reference_to_parent='some_id')
session.add(other)
session.commit()  # <-- sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
```

On commit, I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) insert or update on table "other" violates foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Key (reference_to_parent)=(some_id) is not present in table "parent".
```

However, if I do:

```
child = Child(id='id', other_field="blah")
session.add(child)
session.commit() . # <-- note the extra commit

other = Other(reference_to_parent='id')
session.add(other)
session.commit()
```

I get no such error. It seems that SQLAlchemy doesn't recognise that the child I have added to the session is in fact an instance of `Parent` and will create a row in that table.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It doesn't feel like the commit should be needed.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need add a `session.flush()` after the first add. Flush will basically communicate your changes to the database in a pending state. Commit will actually write them to the database.

```
child = Child(id='some_id', other_field="blah")
session.add(child)
session.flush()

other = Other(id="some_other_id", reference_to_parent='some_id')
session.add(other)
session.commit()
```